# android phonegap application issues in jQuery and UI design

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, rtf, rich-text-editor

I am working on a rich text editor. I do that using following jQuery.
http://www.unverse.net/whizzery/demos/basic.html

It's working fine in all browsers but does not work in emulator and tablets. It will not popup keyboard when we type in textfield. So what should I do to implement rich text editor. I need only basic functionality like bold,italic and underline.

I also want to know about how to set UI of html page.There are various size tablets and screens so how to set UI automatically according to varying screen size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to look at responsive web design techniques to support multiple screen sizes. By using CSS media queries you'll be able to support all sorts of screen sizes. I wrote a mini tutorial here:

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2012/01/on-eight-day-of-phonegapping-multiple.html

Comment: I believe there is one for jQuery but you'll want to look at jQuery Mobile to see what they have as it is built for phones.